# Can I use types to express that at least one argument should be Some for a constructor?

Tags: json, rust

With some help, I've been able to create this code which tries to describe a range of numbers:

```
#[derive(Debug, Default)]
struct Inclusive;
#[derive(Debug, Default)]
struct Exclusive;

#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct Range<S, E, V: Ord>(
    Option<V>,
    Option<V>,
    #[serde(skip)] S,
    #[serde(skip)] E,
);


fn main () {
    let data = "[[1, null]]";
    let rs: Vec<Range<Inclusive, Exclusive, i32>> = serde_json::from_str(data)
         .expect("Error");
    println!("Range from {:?} to {:?}", rs[0].0, rs[0].1);
}
```

Is it possible to describe via types that `Range` should have at least one bound so that `[null, null]` would throw a deserialization error at runtime?

Comment: Do you know what an `enum` is? Have you tried using a custom `enum` instead of a pair of `Option<V>`?

Comment: Yes, I know. What about three parameters or four? Making enum with every possible permutation doesn't scale.

Comment: What about 7 to 97 parameters? With only prime numbers of elements being valid? Not all invariants can be captured statically... at no cost. My advice is to focus on the current case and attempt to solve it as best as possible; when future comes and requirements change, we'll see then.

Comment: @MatthieuM. You wouldn't create a constructor with 97 parameters. I think what I'm asking is a very reasonable requirement and it would be nice if it would be achievable. You seem to be mistaken about the nature of my question. I never said that I'm trying to solve `this particular example of the problem` or that it should be `one of two` arguments. I'm asking about general case. If it's not possible - just say so and explain why it is the case. This would be a valid answer.

Answer (score 2):

It's better to model the problem to capture the invariants statically, rather than relying on runtime checks. Matthieu's suggestion of using an `enum` might look like this:

```
enum RangeBound<V> {
    Between(V, V),
    LowerBounded(V),
    UpperBounded(V),
}

struct Range<S, E, V: Ord>(
    RangeBound<V>,
    #[serde(skip)] S,
    #[serde(skip)] E,
);
```

It is not possible to create a `RangeBound` without at least one value.

This approach will probably require a custom `Deserialize` implementation though.

Comment: Well, I also told about capturing invariants statically. Maybe in this case this is easy with enum, but suppose there would be more than two parameters one on which should be present.